# Get current location using gps not using Lastknownlocation

Tags: android, android-location

I have an application where I need to get my current location I am using

```
setNlocation(locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER));
```

Because of this I am getting last location I also try to use

```
@Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)
    {
        glat = loc.getLatitude();
        glng = loc.getLongitude();

        Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),"GPS Lat:" + glat + "GPS Lng" + glng,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

but that GPS icon is blinking and blinking and blinking .(Not getting GPS Lat Lng of current position)

Comment: GPS takes some time to establish a connection depending on all the variables between you and the satellites. For instance are you inside a building?

Comment: if you are try to get location from  gps then use `LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER` instead of `LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER`.

Comment: @AlexChengalan I am getting LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER faster that GPS

Comment: kindly paste ur rest of code

Comment: Then y did u complaining on that GPS icon..Just keep working.

Comment: I am just asking is there any other way two getting my current location with out this too I option becoz in one case I am getting last GPS location in anther case I have to wait depending on variable as you told

Comment: Network provider will always be faster than GPS. GPS will not work if you're inside a building. If you want to test the GPS connection you must go to the window or outdoors. If want to understand why please read here (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Positioning_System#Basic_concept_of_GPS) that explains why it take so long and why you must be outside.

Comment: Check out this article entitled [Handle Multiple Sources of Location Updates](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/location/currentlocation.html#TaskHandleLocationUpdates)

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.rdcworld-android.blogspot.in/2012/01/get-current-location-coordinates-city.html) is small application with step by step description to gets current locations GPS co-ordinate

```
locationMangaer.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 10,locationListener);
```